# How to draw a vertical line in a list?

Tags: math-mode

I want to typeset what appears in the figure. I use enumerate and tab with \phantom, but the vertical lines over text I dont know how to draw.[image: what I need to draw for my classes reference material about logic] Thanks for any help.

Comment: A possible solution would use a tabular environment and `bigdelim`, which comes with `multirow`.

Comment: Does this construction have to allow for page breaks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possibility. Define a new symbol, which is just `\big|`, except `\smash`ed so it has 0 height and 0 depth (with a space at the end).

```
\newcommand{\vlin}{\smash{\big|}\;}
```

Then if there is no row spacing between the items, the `|` symbols overlap.

[image]

I used the `enumitem` package to control the item separation and have plain numbering with no `.` after the numbers.

```
\begin{enumerate}[nosep,label=\arabic*]
```

I think labeling the items is a good idea so you can reference them without worrying about renumbering later.

I enclosed the left column in `\lefteqn{..}` so any width in that column is ignored. The spacing in the right column can be adjusted by changing the value in `\myspace`.

Lastly, I made new commands for the logical symbols, but that may be unnecessary in your chosen font.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\vlin}{\smash{\big|}\;}
\newcommand{\myspace}{\hspace{5cm}}
\newcommand{\no}{{\sim}}
\newcommand{\amp}{\mathbin{\&}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[nosep,label=\arabic*]
\item\label{npoq} $\lefteqn{\no(P\lor Q)}$\myspace $P$
\item\label{P} $\lefteqn{\vlin P}$\myspace $H$ (para RAA)
\item\label{poq} $\lefteqn{\vlin P\lor Q}$\myspace $\ref{P}\lor \mathrm{I}$
\item\label{poq:nn} $\lefteqn{\vlin P\lor Q\amp\no\no(P\lor Q)}$\myspace \ref{npoq}, \ref{poq} \& I
\item\label{np} $\lefteqn{\no P}$\myspace \ref{P}--\ref{poq:nn} RAA
\item\label{Q} $\lefteqn{\vlin Q}$\myspace $H$ (para RAA)
\item\label{poq2} $\lefteqn{\vlin P\lor Q}$\myspace $\ref{Q}\lor \mathrm{I}$
\item\label{poq:npoq} $\lefteqn{\vlin P\lor Q\amp\no(P\lor Q)}$\myspace \ref{npoq}, \ref{poq2} \& I
\item\label{nq} $\lefteqn{\no Q}$\myspace\ref{Q}--\ref{poq:npoq} RAA
\item $\lefteqn{\no P\amp\no Q}$\myspace\ref{np}, \ref{nq} \& I
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thak you Sandy G. Work even with multi level structures like:

```
\begin{enumerate}[nosep,label=\arabic*]
\item $\lefteqn{(P\wedge Q)\to R}$\myspace [P]
\item $\lefteqn{\vlin P}$\myspace [H p/PC]
\item $\lefteqn{\vlin \vlin Q}$\myspace [H p/PC]
\item $\lefteqn{\vlin \vlin P\wedge Q}$\myspace [$\wedge$I 2,3]
\item $\lefteqn{\vlin \vlin R}$\myspace [MP 4,1]
\item $\lefteqn{\vlin Q\to R}$\myspace [PC 3-5]
\item $\lefteqn{P\to (Q\to R)}$\myspace [PC 2-6]
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, @carlos-campani. You are very welcome, however, on this site the way we generally offer thanks is to [upvote answers that are helpful and accept](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer that best meets your needs. Since this isn't really a new answer, it will probably be removed soon by moderators (or you can delete it yourself). Your response would probably be more appropriate as a comment instead of a new answer. Best wishes.

Comment: OK. But I cant use formats in comments. And my answer complements your answer with multi level structures. Thanks